# Save email from Outlook Online to SharePoint library through an AddIn

Tags: sharepoint-online, .net, outlook-add-in

I have a requirement to a selected email(s) to Outlook through an Add-In. I need it to work with the Outlook client app as well as Outlook Online. I put together a simple VSTO plugin in the Outlook client app which works but I want to do this through an Add-In now.

I have been through this tutorial to save email attachments to OneDrive which has similar functionality. [Attachments to OneDrive Git](https://github.com/officedev/office-add-in-aspnet-sso)

I like the functionality of this and would like to save emails to SharePoint the same way.

Does anyone have a good tutorial for doing this? Or a reference for the libraries? I'll post my progress for others as I get through it. I just haven't been able to find exactly what I'm looking for with this.

Answer (score 0):

There are three out of the box ways to save emails into SharePoint library. For more detailed information, refer to the article below.

[3 out of the box ways to save emails in SharePoint.](https://sharepointmaven.com/3-out-of-the-box-ways-to-save-emails-in-sharepoint/)

And you also could save outlook email to SharePoint programmatically. For more detailed information, refer to the article below.

[Office 365 – Save Outlook e-mails & attachments to SharePoint Online programmatically.](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/01/19/save-outlook-emails-attachments-sharepoint/)

Answer (score 0):

We have created an Outlook AddIn that is working cross platform/device, hence also working for OWA. We have decided to make the Add-In free to all small teams up to 5 persons. The free version has no restrictions, no ads and support full functionality which includes:

- Save emails and attachments to SharePoint, Teams and OneDrive
- Capture email properties automatically
- Attach files to new email including converting to PDF on -the-fly
- Works cross platform and device, i.e. Windows, macOS, iOS, Android, Web

It can be downloaded from our site https://axpoint.com

Hope this free version can help you being more productive